# Detect sudden changes in a time series

Tags: python, time-series, anomaly-detection

I am generating a graph in real time and I am comparing it against a predicted graph.

[image: Sudden Change]

I've discovered the [Kneed](https://github.com/arvkevi/kneed) library for Python but that only works for a specific curve. Only increasing/decreasing graphs as the ones you would find in an increasing computer load for example.

I don't know if this is possible in a remote way without adding so much complexity and mathematical calculus. As I have been investigating the mathematical approach would be to work with the second derivative but this being a discrete array not a continuous one complicates everything.

Is there a simpler way to be able to detect when these sudden changes are happening with Python?

Answer (score 0):

The kind of anomaly you have there would be easily detected by:

- Compute the median of the last N samples.
- For a new sample, compute the distance to the window median. This will be the anomaly score

Do this across a representative dataset of normal values. Plot the histogram of anomaly scores and set a threshold to be just outside the range of normal values.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways:

- Median test
- Quadrate box diagram
- Rate of change
- Vector map